# How much memory should be used if one table have a 1TB size of index

Tags: mysql

If a table has a primary key (bigint) with 1TB size of index.

So If I want to search `id = ?` in this table should I have the hardware requirement is greater than 1TB of RAM?

P/S: I don't know how about the hardware requirement should to buy to test it.

**Updated:**

Table:

```
id          bigint - primary key
value       bigint - index
```

Storage: InnoDb.
Number of rows I need to store: 30-60 billions.

Comment: How large is the table and what is the type of the index?  What are you storing?  A bigint index would support 125 billion rows.  That is a log of rows.   I suspect your data model could be improved.

Comment: I am going to update my question.

Comment: No you do not need a more ram than the size of the index.  It will be an index seek.  If if it was scan it would still not require memory bigger than the index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In terms of performance, maybe.  In terms of hardware requirements, then "no".  SQL knows how to manage data structure larger than memory.

A 125 *billion* rows in a table is (even nowadays) a large table.  You are using a `bigint` so you are expecting lots of rows.  Of course, things work best when the index can just reside in memory.  I don't want to argue against 1Tbyte+ of memory for this purpose.

You can partition on the `id` column and significantly reduce the memory requirements.  This would be particularly helpful if the typical usage of the id is for a range of ids.  For instance, if the id is assigned sequentially and 99% of the ids are for the past day, then you can (essentially) partition by data by days.  You would really be partitioning the data by the minimum id value on each day, but it would have the same effect.

So, if you had 1,000 days of data, then you would only need 1 Gbyte for the index for this partition.  You can have a few more Gbytes for indexes for other partitions.  Note that searching on ids from other days would require loading the partition index into memory, which is additional overhead.

This solution can work depending entirely on the query load.  If you need to randomly access all the rows in the index, then the best structure is likely to be storing the entire index in memory.

Answer (score 1):

No you don't need more memory than the size of the index.  SQL will bring pages into memory (I think they are 2K).  When it runs of memory it will just take the page out of memory.   An index seek will require very little memory.  Even an index scan does does not require the full index to be in memory (at any one time).